# React Native this.props in a Fetch JSON

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'am trying to get data JSON fetch from an API from my server in React Native but now I'm trying to get also the results based on latitude and longitude. Here is my code to fetch the JSON:

```
 async componentDidMount() {
try {
  const response = await
    fetch('https://example.com/api/?latitude='+{{this.state.latitude}}+'&longitude='+{{this.state.longitude}}+'');
  const responseJson = await response.json();
  this.setState({
    isLoading: false,
    isFetching: false,
    dataSource: responseJson.locations,
  }, function () { });
}
catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

}

But this doesn't work.
If I do:

```
<Text>{this.state.latitude}</Text>
```

the location latitude is viewing so there are no error's with getting the location information itself.

Thanks in advance for helping me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
_getLocationAsync = async () => {
let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
if (status !== 'granted') {
  this.setState({
    errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
  });
  return;  // add this
}

console.log("Permission granted") // add this and see if you really get permission or not
let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
console.log("location", location);
this.setState({ location });};
```

Comment: I’m not getting an error but my FlatList is empty. If I hard code the latitude and longitude the FlatList is filled with content

Comment: Did you try changing the url to the one I sent.

Comment: What is the initial state of the component ?

Comment: Yes I did, and the initial state is this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      isFetching: false,
    };

Comment: How are you getting the `latitude` and `longitude` then ?

Comment: Look at my new comment on the post

Comment: Are you getting some error ? Or is your location not showing up ?

Comment: I'm not getting the location and especially in the fetch. If I do there a console log I get undefined. And also the FlatList is not showing anything. I have a pull to refresh function so I only see the ActivityIndicator and that's it

Comment: I updated my answer, please check it. Confirm if you are getting the permission or not.

Comment: Yes I get Permission is granted

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
location: null,
errorMessage: null,};
```

Then

```
componentWillMount() {
if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Constants.isDevice) {
  this.setState({
    errorMessage: 'Oops, this will not work on Sketch in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!',
  });
} else {
  this._getLocationAsync();
}}
```

Then

```
_getLocationAsync = async () => {
let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
if (status !== 'granted') {
  this.setState({
    errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
  });
}

let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
this.setState({ location });};
```

Then

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  isLoading: true,
  isFetching: false,
  location:null
};}
```